# Javascript: all arrangements of n arrays with n values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

If I had a collection like this:

```
var array = {
    "fruit": ["apple","banana"],
    "amount": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "orign": ["africa", "asia", "europe"],
    ...
    "n": ["0", "...", "n"]
}
```

How would I get all combinations in a JSON format like this:

```
[
 {
   "fruit": "apple",
   "amount": "1",
   "orign": "africa"
 }
 {
   "fruit": "apple",
   "amount": "1",
   "orign": "asia"
 }
 ...
]
```

Is it possible to loop through all elements in a iterative manner? Or would I end up writing n loops?

Comment: You could do this: 

`const arrays = Object.values({
    "fruit": ["apple","banana"],
    "amount": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "orign": ["africa", "asia", "europe"]
  });
  
const f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(d => b.map(e => [].concat(d, e))));
  
const cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => (b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a);
  
console.log(cartesian(...arrays));`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the "cartesian product" (assuming the arrays are sets). Your question (in a slightly different way) has been previously discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript).  You can see different solutions in there, including a recursive solution, and many functional programming like.

I hope it helps,

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! The cartesian product seems to be right approach